# Parsing variables within a string using a Regular Expression

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I've got a bit of a problem with regular expressions with ColdFusion.

I have a string:

```
Hi my name is {firstname}. and i live in {towncity} my email address is {email}
```

What I would like to know is how would I go about finding all strings, within my string, that are encased within a set of `{}` brackets? I would like to split all the matching strings into an array so I can use the results of query data.

Also is this a commonly used pattern for processing strings within matching strings for merging variable data ?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The coldfusion tags reFind() and reReplace() might be useful.  Regular exresssions are not my strong suit so I'd have to look on the internet to find one.  ColdFusion also has an arrayappend() function that you can use to populate an array, but the part about using the results of query data as a reason for the array sounds strange.

Answer (score 5):

#### Simple Answer

To find all the brace-encased strings, you can use [rematch](http://cfdocs.org/rematch) and the simple expression `\{[^{}]+\}`

#### Explanation

The backslashes `\` before each brace are to escape them, and have them act as literal braces (they carry special meaning otherwise).

The `[^`...`]` is a negative character class, saying match any single char that is NOT one of those contained within, and the greedy `+` quantifier tells it to match as many as possible, but at least one, from the preceding item.

Thus using `[^{}]+` between the braces means it will not match nested or unmatched braces. (Whilst using `\{.*?\}` could match two opening braces. Note: the `*?` is a lazy quantifier, it matches nothing (if possible), but as many as required.)

#### Extended Answer

However, since you say that the results come from a query, a way to only match the values you're dealing with is to use the query's ColumnList to form an expression:

```
`\{(#ListChangeDelims(QueryName.ColumnList,'|')#)\}`
```

This changes ColumnList into a pipe-delimited list - a set of alternatives, grouped by the parentheses - i.e. the generated pattern will be like:

```
 \{(first_name|towncity|email)\}
```

(with the contents of that group going into capture group 1).

To actually populate the text (rather than just matching) you could do something similar, except there is no need for a regex here, just a straight [replace](http://cfdocs.org/replace) whilst looping through columns:

```
<cfloop index="CurColumn" list=#QueryName.ColumnList#>
    <cfset text = replace( text , '{#CurColumn#}' , QueryName[CurColumn][CurrentRow] , 'all' ) />
</cfloop>
```

(Since this is a standard replace, there's no need to escape the braces with backslashes; they have no special meaning here.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `reMatch(reg_expression, string_to_search)` function.

The details on Regular Expressions in Coldfusion 10 are [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html). (I believe the regexp in CF8 would be roughly the same.)

Use the following code.

```
<cfset str = "Hi my name is {firstname}. And I live in {towncity} my email address is {email}.">
<cfoutput>Search string: <b>#str#</b><br />Search result:<br /></cfoutput>
<cfset ret = reMatch("\{[\w\s\(\)\+\.@-]+\}", str)>
<cfdump var ="#ret#">
```

This returns an array with the following entries.

- {firstname}
- {towncity}
- {email}

The `[]` brackets in CF regular expressions define a character set to match a single character. You put `+` after the brackets to match one or more characters from the character set defined inside the `[]`. For example, to **match one or more** upper case letters you could write `[A-Z]+`.

As detailed in the link above, CF defines shortcuts to match various characters. The ones I used in the code are: `\w` to match an alpha-numeric character or an underscore, `\s` to match a whitespace character (including space, tab, newline, etc.).

To match the following special characters `+*?.[^$({|\` you escape them by writing backslash `\` before them.

An exception to this is the dash `-` character, which cannot be escaped with a backslash. So, to use it as a literal simply place it at the very end of the character set, like I did above.

Using the above regular expression you can extract characters from the following string, for example.

```
<cfset str = "Hi my name is { John Galt}. And I live in {St. Peters-burg } my email address is {john@exam_ple.com}.">
```

The result would be an array with the following entries.

- { John Galt}
- {St. Peters-burg }
- {john@exam_ple.com}

Comment: You don't need all those escapes - `[\w\s\(\)\+\.@-]` works the same as `[\w\s()+.@-]` - but even then, there's no reason not to just use the even simpler `[^{}]`.

Also - _"An exception to this is the dash - character, which cannot be escaped with a backslash."_ - this is incorrect. The dash is one of the few characters that _needs_ to be escaped to be a literal inside a character class, and prevent it forming a range.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But I believe you do need those escapes because without them regexp doesn't work. The `[\w\s()+.@-]` does not match anything and `[^{}]` retrieves characters individually (given the first string in my example, `reMatch()` returns an array with 74 entries).

Comment: I believe my comment about the dash `-` is correct. According to documentation (link in my post) "you cannot escape it _[the dash]_ as you can other special characters because ColdFusion always interprets a hyphen as a range indicator. Therefore, if you use a literal hyphen in a character set, make it the last character in the set." So in that sense the dash is unescapable (in Coldfusion at least). Although, I must say that this behaviour might not be standard when compared to regular expressions in other languages.

Comment: Both `[\w\s()+.@-]` and `[^{}]` work fine when replacing the contents between the `\{` and `+\}` in your code example - all versions return the same three element array.

Comment: To see that hyphens do work escaped, here is an example: `<cfdump var=#rematch('[a\-c]','abc-123_')#>` - if literal, you get `['a','c','-']`, if a range, you get `['a','b','c','_']`

Comment: (I'm not impressed with Coldfusion at all.)

Answer (score 0):

There may be much better ways to do this, but using something like `rematch( '{.*?}', yourstring )` would give you an array of all the matches.

For future reference, I did this with the excellent [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), a really nice online regex checker. Full disclosure, it's not *specifically* for ColdFusion, but it's a great way to test things out.

Comment: Whilst this works in CF's regex engine, it should be noted that in many other engines this would cause a syntax error - `{` and `}` should be escaped with a backslash when used as literal characters. Also, note that (despite being lazy) this could match too much - if the input contains `abc{def {ghi} jkl` the match would be `{def {ghi}`.

Comment: Sure, but that would be a valid match based on the request made in the original request.

Comment: It's not mentioned in the original request, so is undefined how it show behave, but based on the information provided it's almost certainly not what is wanted - database column names don't have braces in them.